# Google V8 JavaScript Engine - How to set a value to null?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

Using the V8 engine, how do I set a value to `null`? Basically I want to return a variable from a C++ addon to JavaScript, and the variable needs to be set to `null` under certain conditions.

Comment: I was actually wondering -- i see JS, node.js, and V8 tags, and wanted to eliminate the obvious.

Comment: @cHao - Good point, I removed the JavaScript tag to attempt to avoid any more confusion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can explicitly return `null` via [`v8::Null`](http://izs.me/v8-docs/namespacev8.html#aa6bb9749edb4ef25314964762bc4d5e8):

```
return scope.Close( Null() );
```

---

Also, it turns out that if a `Value` variable is declared, it is automatically assigned to `undefined`. For example, the following returns `undefined` back to JavaScript:

```
 HandleScope scope;
 Local<Value> result;
 ...

 return scope.Close(result);
```

Comment: No, there is no implicit initialization with null value. Here `result` will be an *empty* handle. To explicitly initialize it with `null` you can use `v8::Null()` function.

Comment: Hmm... but the empty handle is interpreted as `null` back in the JavaScript code. Is this guaranteed by v8 or did I just get lucky?

Comment: Empty handle is interpretet as `undefined`. JavaScript defines that `null == undefined` is true, but `null === undefined` is false.

Comment: @Vyacheslav - That makes sense... in any case, I modified my code to explicitly return null, per your recommendation. Thanks so much for all of your help!

Comment: use ```v8::Null(isolate)```;

Comment: @dreampulse - `isolate`?

Comment: @JustinEthier Null expects one parameter
`Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();`
`v8::Null(isolate);`